# Attempt to index field '_target' (a number value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to dressup a delete function, but getting this error :

`Attempt to index field '_target' (a number value)`

Code snippet:

```
   for i = #badC1T, 1, -1 do
        if badC1T[i] ~= nil then

            transition.to( i, {  time=500, alpha=0,} )

            local function dellBadC1T()
                badC1T[i]:removeSelf()
                badC1T[i] = nil
            end

            timer.performWithDelay( 500, dellBadC1T, 1 )
        end
    end
```

any idea how i can fix this ?

Comment: what's the content of `badC1T` array?

Are You sure You've meant `badC1T[i]:removeSelf()` instead if `badC1T[i].removeSelf()`?

Comment: @Kamiccolo the removeSelf function works its the 'transition.to( i, {  time=500, alpha=0,} )' that creates the error

Comment: According to [documentation](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/to.html) You should pass a `Target object` to `transitio.to()` as first argument. So, it would be problably `badC1T[i]` instead of `i`.

Might be `transition.to( badC1T[i], {  time=500, alpha=0,} )`. Can't really say, unless You provide information about `badC1T` content.

Comment: @Kamiccolo  your right transition.to( badC1T[i], { time=500, alpha=0,} ) works like a charm :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [CoronaSDK documentation](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/to.html) first parameter of `transition.to()` *MUST* be a `Target object`. But You're passing a number `i`.

Fix might look like this:

`transition.to( badC1T[i], { time=500, alpha=0,} )`